# How to find a file using a pattern?

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I have a script that is supposed to grab a file from a folder and attach it to an email.

The code runs but nothing happens. I assume it's because strLocation is empty.

Here is an example of the file path I am trying to grab:

"C:\Users\MChambers\Desktop\Pricing Reports\Pricing_Report_201908121239 Formatted.xlsx"

```
Option Explicit

Const olMailItem = 0

Function FindFirstFile(strDirPath, strPattern)
    Dim strResult

    Dim objRegExp, objMatches
    Set objRegExp = New RegExp
    objRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

    Dim objFso, objFolder, objFile
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirPath)

    For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
        Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(objFile.Name)
        If objMatches.Count > 0 Then
            strResult = objMatches(0).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Len(strResult) > 0 Then
        If Right(strDirPath, 1) <> "\" Then strDirPath = strDirPath & "\"
        strResult = strDirPath & strResult
    End If

    FindFirstFile = strResult
End Function

Sub SendBasicEmail()
    Dim olApp: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim olEmail: Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Dim strLocation
    Dim strPattern
    strPattern = "Pricing_Report_*Formatted.xlsx"
    strLocation = FindFirstFile("C:\Users\MChambers\Desktop\Pricing Reports\", strPattern)

    If strLocation <> "" Then
        With olEmail 
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "genericemail"
            .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
            .To = "myemail"
            .Subject = "Subject"
            .Send
        End With
    End If
End Sub

SendBasicEmail
```

Update: The solution below was correct. In addition, I had to call the sub directly at the end of the file which I have updated in the code above.

Comment: Have you actually tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're using doesn't do what you apparently think it does.

```
strPattern = "Pricing_Report_*Formatted.xlsx"
```

You seem to expect the above to do a wildcard match (i.e. "Pricing_Report_" followed by any amount of text and "Formatted.xlsx"). That is not how regular expressions work. `*` in a regular expression means "zero or more times the preceding expression". The character `.` also has a special meaning in regular expressions, which is "any character except line-feed. Because of that your pattern would actually match the string "Pricing_Report" followed by any number of consecutive underscores, the string "Formatted", any single character except line-feed, and the string "xlsx".

Change the pattern to this

```
strPattern = "Pricing_Report_.*Formatted\.xlsx"
```

and the code will do what you want.

For further information about regular expressions in VBScript [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/6wzad2b2(v=vs.84)).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer.